# Referencing external JS library in typescript

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I would like to use Jquery library in my type script(.ts) file , and I using
atom editor.

To implement this I have followed below steps

1. Since I am using atom editor , installed apm install atom-typescript
2. Since Jquery is external JS library , I have dowloaded typed defination
   from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) and placed the file in my application folder

3 Added reference to jquery.d.ts" in my test.ts file

Below is the test.ts code

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.d.ts" />

export class test {
$("#testID").val("test"); // editor shows ERROR in this line , "parameter    declaration expected"
 }
```

Please let me know what is that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copy-pasting the definition file, it is considered best practice to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) instead. Typings handles a lot for you, eg. you won't have to think about referencing the proper path.

So just run `typings init` and `typings install --save --global dt~jquery` and you should be good to go.